# $.ajax not calling WebService in ASP.Net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, web-services

I am trying to call webservice through jQuery but it is not showing any results or errors. My code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    var empId = '<%= Session["UserName"] %>';
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    alert(empId);    
    $.ajax({ 
        type: "POST", 
        dataType: "json", 
        contentType: "application/json", 
        url: "ServiceGetUser.asmx/GetEmployee", 
        data: "{'employeeId': '" + empId + "'}", 
        success: function (data) { 
            alert("Employee name: " + data.d); 
        }, 
        error: function () { 
            alert("Error calling the web service.");  
        } 
    }); 
</script>
```

I'm getting a value from `session` printing it successfully then passing it to the webservice and in return printing name `Jane Developer` as shown in my webservice code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Services.Protocols;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace MentorMentee
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for ServiceGetUser
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class ServiceGetUser : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]
        public string GetEmployee(string employeeId)
        {
            return "Jane Developer";
        }
    }
}
```

what's wrong is going on hopes for your suggestions

Thanks

Comment: **{'employeeId': empId },** <- tried this way.

Comment: attach debugger on your web-service and see whether web-service is getting hitted

Comment: i use debugger but its not calling it :(

Comment: @jai this is format which i get freom MCTS training kit program 70-515

Comment: @ all i got error in IE that "$" is undefined near "$.ajax" thats why not firing webservice :(

Comment: @ now i am getting error calling the webservice ???

Comment: Error resolver as i am document .ready thats why its not recognizing "$" of $.ajax ! Thanks all

Comment: $ is undefined means you must have not referred the jquery library at the point where `$.ajax` is called. checked that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put this in `doc ready block`:

```
$(window).load(function(){
   $.ajax({ 
      type: "POST", 
      dataType: "json", 
      contentType: "application/json", 
      url: "ServiceGetUser.asmx/GetEmployee", 
      data: {'employeeId': '<%= Session["UserName"] %>'}, //<-- try it
      success: function (data) { 
          alert("Employee name: " + data.d); 
      }, 
      error: function () { 
          alert("Error calling the web service.");  
      } 
    });
 });
```

Comment: actually i wanna call it on page load when i put it in document block it do not call even

Comment: You can call it in jquery's version of window load. updated the answer.

Comment: @Jai: +1, a better practise will be `var DTO = { employeeID : '<%= Session["UserName"] %>'};` and then pass DTO as `data: JSON.stringify( DTO )`

Answer (score 1):

dataType is given as json. Which means that jquery will parse the response received from server into json. But you are returning string in your service. So parse error will be thrown by jQuery.

Try attaching `complete(jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus)` callback. And look at  textStatus

Try using

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    var empId = '<%= Session["UserName"] %>';
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    alert(empId);    
    $.ajax({ 
        type: "POST", 
        dataType: "json", 
        contentType: "application/json", 
        url: "ServiceGetUser.asmx/GetEmployee", 
        data: "{'employeeId': '" + empId + "'}", 
        success: function (data) { 
            alert("Employee name: " + data.d); 
        }, 
        error: function () { 
            alert("Error calling the web service.");  
        } ,
        complete: function(xhr, textStatus) {
            alert(textStatus);
        }
    }); 
</script>
```

Comment: then what data type should be chang to maki it in working condition ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    var empId = '<%= Session["UserName"] %>';
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    alert(empId);    
    $.ajax({ 
        type: "POST", 
        dataType: "json", 
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
        url: "ServiceGetUser.asmx/GetEmployee", 
        data: '{employeeId: "' + $("#<%=employeeId.ClientID%>")[0].value + '" }',
        success: function (data) { 
            alert("Employee name: " + data.d); 
        }, 
        error: function () { 
            alert("Error calling the web service.");  
        } 
    }); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First try to stringify your json like this
`alert(JSON.stringify(data))` then maybe u can find your mistake..